# This page isn’t working www.example.co.ke is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I recently deployed my laravel project to production and hosted it to live server in cpanel.all other pages are working well but when try i uploading data to the database ,i get this error **HTTP error 500 [www.example.co.ke](http://www.example.co.ke) is currently unable to handle this request.**.The upload code works well in localhost but on live server it throws the above error.
[image: error]
How can i fix this

Comment: just look at the error log. It will tell you all you need to know

Comment: @CornelRaiu where can i see the error log. my web app is in production.

Comment: you should be able to see it in the `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: @CornelRaiu apparently on the log file i cant find any error

Comment: The first log to check, is the php/fpm error. To read the content, it depend on the hosting type. You must read the doc of your hosting provider. Also, make sure you use the right database credentials.

Comment: one of the first things to check in this case is your .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see the error log in the logs folder and saw where the error was coming from.